# What is the gist meaning of the paragraph?

Tags: meaning-in-context, american-english

She had taken to wondering lately, during with all those wasted summer days; how could she have spent them so wantonly? I am foolish, she told herself early every summer, I am very foolish; I am grown up now and know the values of things. Nothing is ever really wasted, she believed sensibly, even one's childhood, and then each year, one summer morning, the warm wind would come down the city  street where she walked and she would be touched with the little cold thought: I have let more time go by.

Comment: What do you think it means? What parts are you unsure about?

Comment: @randomhead I'm confused about everything. I literally searched all the meaning of every single words that I don't know. But the paragraph still doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: 'during with' doesn't make sense and must be an error.

Comment: Also "gist" means "meaning", so "gist meaning" is redundant and ungrammatical.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my summary of the paragraph.

In the paragraph, the girl is contemplating (thinking) about the time wasted during the summers. She assures herself that she has not done anything wrong by doing nothing during summers. She believes that being a grown up she knows the value of experiencing little things, such as the wind on the face when walking down the street. She thinks that she must let more of her time without any care to experience the good things.